# How to connect Amazon QLDB database in Spring boot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-qldb

I have a ledger-based database "demo" inside AWS qLdB. So I want to connect to that database through the Spring boot web application.

First of all, I gave user permissions to QLDB like

[image]

Then I added the following maven dependencies to pom.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-qldb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-qldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.ion/ion-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.ion</groupId>
            <artifactId>ion-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.qldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-qldb-driver-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

In Application.yml i kept these properties.

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      access-key: 
      secret-key: 
    region: US East (Ohio)
```

Then I create a config class to connect to QLDB like.

```
@Configuration
public class QldbConfigs {
    public static IonSystem ionSys = IonSystemBuilder.standard().build();
    public static QldbDriver qldbDriver;

    @Bean
    public void setupDb(){
        System.out.println("Initializing the driver");
        qldbDriver = QldbDriver.builder()
                .ledger("demo")
                .transactionRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy
                        .builder()
                        .maxRetries(3)
                        .build())
                .sessionClientBuilder(QldbSessionClient.builder())
                .build();
    }
}
```

If I run this, it is giving an exception like

***software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain@6076c66: [software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@57b1ec84: Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)., software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsProfileRegionProvider@5a82bc58: No region provided in profile: default, software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider@5d37aa0f: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.]***

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK will look in [a set of predefined places](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) to find some credentials to supply to the service when it connects. According to [the Spring Boot documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/getting-started-with-spring-boot-on-aws-part-1/):

> Spring Cloud for AWS can automatically detect this based on your environment or stack once you enable the Spring Boot property cloud.aws.region.auto.
>
> You can also set the region in a static fashion for your application:

```yaml
cloud:
 aws:
   region:
     static: eu-central-1
     auto: false
```

Which is different from the way you are configuring your region in your example. To be completely sure, you can set the region directly on the `QldbSessionClient.builder` as follows.

```java
qldbDriver = QldbDriver.builder()
  .ledger("demo")
  .transactionRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy
    .builder()
    .maxRetries(3)
    .build())
  .sessionClientBuilder(
    QldbSessionClient.builder().region(Region.of("us-east-1")))
  .build();
```